# Is this C# Console code correct?

Tags: c#

I am admittedly inexperienced with C#/OOP, but I recently came across this code and it feels incorrect to me even though it does appear to functionally work.  The code is from a console application.

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static private double Theta{ get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ...
      var thetaString = Console.ReadLine();
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(thetaString))
        Theta = Math.PI * Double.Parse(thetaString) / 180.0;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the static declaration from Theta, it will no longer compile.  If I remove the {get; set}, it functions just as it did previously.  What is this code doing?  What is the significance of the accessors?

Comment: Does it work as expected? If so - it's correct, otherwise it's not.

Comment: Why do you feel that this is incorrect?  What do you think that it *should* be?

Comment: static functions cannot access instance variables, properities etc.

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: `Theta` is an [auto property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Comment: Yes.  The code functions as it says it does.

Comment: Then it's correct. Case closed.

Comment: A static method cannot access instance members (unless of course it has an instance from which to reference the members).  That is why you can't remove `static` from the Theta declaration.  Without the accessors, you are defining a field, which is a storage location.  With the accessors, you are defining a property, which is one or two methods that modify a storage location.  The general preference is for properties, though the reasons for that are mostly significant for instance properties rather than static properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I remove the static declaration from Theta, it will no longer compile

That is because you're trying to access an *instance* property from a static method.  You would need to create an instance of `Program` to access a non-static property.

> What is the significance of the accessors?

They allow you do define *methods* that get/set values rather than just a field that stores a value.  There are other more subtle differences, most of which are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c).  In my option the most significant are:

- Changing a field to a property is a breaking change - clients must be rebuilt against the new assembly to incorporate the change.  Changing an auto-implemented property to one that has actual code is *not* a breaking change.
- Most databinding methods use reflection and only support binding to properties.